# Delphi TWebbrowser response code

Tags: delphi, web, browser, http-status-code-404

Is there any way to check browser response after page loading in Delphi? For example I have addresses like http://page0001.html 0002 0003 etc…

And some of them do not exists, so I want browser to load only those that does. I want to do it in cycle starting with 1 till 500 and those that are existing will be collected into array and displayed, so what should be the response condition to check?

Something like page loaded = ok, not loaded 404, so how to do it in Delphi?

Comment: you don't need a `TWebbrowser` for that, you can use `TIdHttp.Get()` and check if the `ResponseCode `is 404.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to check the response first and only load the ones that return OK? And why load lots of pages in advance using a GUI control? Perhaps better to load on demand and not waste bandwidth. And if you load ahead of time surely better to load with non-GUI code. Then you can do so async in a thread.

Comment: Thanks for replies guys, yep David, that is what i tried to ask, maybe just wrote it incorrecty, so i want FIRST to check and collect exisiting pages and once collected -- start loading them into Browser's different tabs.

Comment: You can send a HEAD request to only check if the resource exists. The method TIdHTTP.Head does this, and returns a HTTP status code.

Comment: I also forgot to mention the pages are https...

Comment: <!-- language: lang-pascal -->
IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    IdHTTP.HandleRedirects:= True;
    IdHTTP.ReadTimeout:= 10000;
    link:=request.Text;
    try IdHTTP.Head(link);
       webbrowser1.Navigate(link);
     except
      showmessage('Page not found 404');
    end;
<>